# Setting state along with AsyncStorage in useEffect hook causes infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

I'm new to `hooks` and recently started using hooks in my React Native projects.

I'm building a simple todo app using the `AsyncStorage`. First I initialize initial `data` and `setData` state using `useState` hook:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

There are two `textInput` and submit button that I use to save data to AsyncStorage. Here is the `saveData` function:

```
const saveData = async () => {
  const arrData = [{ name: 'vikrant', phone: 123456 }]; // [{ name, phone}] from the textInput

  const storedData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
  const storedDataParsed = JSON.parse(storedData);

  let newData = [];

  if (storedData === null) {
    // save
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(arrData));
  } else {
    newData = [...storedDataParsed, user];
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(newData));
  }
  setName('');
  setPhone('');
  Keyboard.dismiss();
};
```

Now, I'm using `useEffect` to get data from the AsyncStorage and setting it to the `data` state. I'm using data to render the text in the screen.

```
useEffect(() => {
  retrieveData();
}, [data]);

const retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const valueString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    const value = JSON.parse(valueString);
    setData(value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I'm using `[data]` in useEffect since I want to re-render my component each time  data changes i.e. each time I save data in AsyncStorage. But this is causing infinite loop as `setData` causes useEffect to run infinitely.

If I remove `data` from the `[]` it doesn't loop but my data in render is one step behind. So whenever I save data it doesn't show the current data but the previous one.

Any explanation of what I am doing wrong here and how can i fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned by you, the infinite loop is due to thefact that you pass `data` as a dependency to `useEffect` and also set in inside the function called in useEffect.

The solution here is to not use useEffect and instead setData whenever you are setting value in AsyncStorage

```
const saveData = async () => {
  const arrData = [{ name: 'vikrant', phone: 123456 }]; // [{ name, phone}] from the textInput

  const storedData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
  const storedDataParsed = JSON.parse(storedData);

  let newData = [];

  if (storedData === null) {
    // save
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(arrData));
  } else {
    newData = [...storedDataParsed, user];
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(newData));
  }
  setName('');
  setPhone('');
  setData(newData);
  Keyboard.dismiss();
};
```

Comment: ok so no need of useEffect then? Let me try to do it by your way.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a conditional flag, `retrieve` to wrap async storage, `retrieveData()`, calls.

Also in the context of "saving data" I would probably just separate async storage-ish logic with state logic. Current `saveData` is polluted with both state and async storage logic.

Something like:

```
const [retrieve, setRetrieve] = useState(false);

// Pure AsyncStorage context
const saveData = async () => {
  ...
  if (storedData === null) {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(arrData));
  } else {
    newData = [...storedDataParsed, user];
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(newData));
  }
  // XXX: Removed state logic, call it somewhere else.
};

const someHandler = async () => {
  await saveData();
  setRetrieve(true); // to signal effect to call retrieveData()
}
```

Then the goal of the effect is just to run `retrieveData()` once saving is done.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
      const valueString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
      const value = JSON.parse(valueString);
      // Other set states
      setData(value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  // Retrieve if has new data
  if (retrieve)
    retrieveData();
    setRetrieve(false);
  }
}, [retrieve]);
```

Comment: let me try this. Thanks.

Comment: Looping issue is fixed but data is not rendering when saving.

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 updated. I've checked there's no need for `data` to be in `useEffect` dependency. The goal of the effect is just to retrieve from async storage or not.

Comment: I removed data but the problem still persist. Not sure why.

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 refer to how the flag is set after calling `saveData()`